# how jQuery event bubbling works?

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul id="level1">
     <li id="level21">item1</li>
     <li id="level22">item2</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to do event bubbling for the child class `<li>` using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#level1').on('click', function(event){
         alert($(this) + ',' + event);
    });
});
```

This code does not trigger event bubbling for both `<li>` class. 
Is this because the child classes do not have click events for them?
I still don't understand when event bubbling would be triggered?

Comment: Bubbling occurs from innermost child to parent. So if you define it on inner `li`; click will trigger of inner `li` first and then on subsequent parents.

Comment: thanks for the fast post. i am aware that clicking on the `<li>` will trigger the event as well but why do I not see the a chain of events that start from the li and go to the parent class ie. two alerts, one for the child `<li>` and one for the parent `<ul>`?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: So basically event bubbling always happens when an event is triggered. In my code, if I were to assign another click event on the `<li>` elements, that would trigger two alerts right? but I still don't understand why a click event is triggered for the `<li>` element even though I didn't assign it one? there is no event capturing in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ul>` element is wrapping the `<li>` elements, that's why the alert triggers when you click either of the items. Same happens for every DOM element that you attach a click event to - all child elements will trigger the event when clicked on (unless you stop the propagation by calling `event.stopPropagation()`).

It has, at the moment, nothing to do with event bubbling. As the comments state correctly, bubbling is when the event triggers for the element, and then trigger for parent elements in sequence.

Your comment is also correct. If you attached an event for an `li`, you'll see two alerts as you can see in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3zoykbm/) I made.

Comment: thanks a lot. so is it because of inheritance that the child elements get the methods (functions) as well?

Comment: @blank_kuma Exactly :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. All of you guys clarified a lot for me :)